# Extracting a content from an xml file using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Hi everyone I have problem on extracting the string on this tag composition.

```
<text:p>ス<text:span text:style-name="T1">イ</text:span>カ</text:p>
```

I want to get all the characters inside `text:p` and `text:span` tag.

Output should look like this `スイカ`

How can I compose an xpath pattern to extract above?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these xpath expressions on the xml in your question:

```
//*[local-name()='text:p']
```

or

```
//text:p
```

or

```
string(//text:p)
```

The output should be:

```
スイカ
```

Comment: Still will output the `スカ`

Comment: @Joppx - Can you edit the question and show your actual code?